# Get ID count from Database and generate dynamic links to news

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamic

Yesterday I asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117767/add-dynamic-content-to-otherwise-static-php-page
I´m sorry for the not very precise question. I accomplished a lot more now by myself but I still have a few questions.

I managed to put my news into a Database Table with the following columns:
"id", "news_headline", "news_date", "news_teaser", "news_content", "news_external_link"

On my news/index.php I have the following code now:

```
<?php
     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXX", "oizQvdjh", "usr_web3_1");
     // Check connection
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
     $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_news ORDER BY id DESC");

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
       echo "<li class='clearfix'>";
       echo "<a class='news_pic'><img src='/assets/images/news/news_".$row['id']
                  ."_thumb.jpg'></a>";
       echo "<h2 class='info_headline'>" . $row['news_headline'] . "</h2>";
       echo "<p class='date'>" . $row['news_date'] 
                  . " &ndash; <a href='#disqus_thread'></a></p>";
       echo "<p class='news_text'>" . $row['news_teaser'] 
                  . "<br><a class='more-link' href='WHERE_TO'>Read more</a></p>";
       echo "</li>";
     }

     mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Everything looks great there and it fetches all my news from the database (five so far) and gets the image which I uploaded by myself on the server with names according to the id.

The single News side has the same code except it has a "WHERE" statement and grabs the content text and not the teaser:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE id='1' ORDER BY id DESC");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<h2>" . $row['news_headline'] . "</h2>";
   echo "<p class='date'>" . $row['news_date'] 
         . " &ndash; <a href='#disqus_thread'></a></p>";
   echo "<a class='news_pic'><img src='/assets/images/news/news_".$row['id']."
         .jpg'></a>";
   echo "<p class='news_text'>" . $row['news_content'] . "</p>";
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Now to my question. How do I have to save the file of the single news to get it dynamically updatet. In my Index where the href says "WHERE TO" I want a link like `<a href="<?php echo $row['news_date'] + slug` (I would add a column slug in my table).

The news single php should then be generated and should also say the date and slug in the URL. Like XXX/news/2013-02-18_this-is-a-news-site.php
I know that for that I also have to put a variable into the WHERE command: Instead of `WHERE id=1` --> id="GET AUTOMATICALLY". I also don´t know what to put here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, by the way:

You need to enable mod_rewrite and choose an appropriate rewrite rule.

Create an .htaccess file like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

An url like

```
http://your.site.com/news/2012/10/22
```

Will be converted to

```
http://your.site.com/index.php?path=/news/2012/10/22
```

Get 'path' from querystring and create your query. Be sure to sanitize input properly.

2012/10/22 is almost a mysql valid date: just replace '/' with '-'.

```
$dt=str_replace('/','-',substr($path,6));
```

Ensure it is a valid date:

```
$dt=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dt));
```

Now your query could be

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE news_date='$dt'";
```

This query will give you all news for a specific day.

Comment: I don´t think this is what I need, or at least not all. I need a functionality like in Wordpress for example. There I have a php file "single.php" where all my single post content gets added from the database. I need something like this for my single-news site as well so that I have only one file with all the code in it. 
From my news index site I link to this side with a dynamically added date+slug that gets grabbed from the database.

Comment: It's the same. Adjust Rewrite rule and use the script you want.

Comment: Hmm ok... I´ll try to figure it out. What would I have to put in my href="" on my news index page then?
And my other question about what to put in the single news page instead of: WHERE id=1. How do I get the current id?

Comment: Extract year, month and day from the 'path' variable, convert to date with timetostr(), create a mysql date format with $mdt=date('Y-m-d',$dt), then use a query to select your news, like `SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE news_date='$mdt'`

Comment: @ghigo you need rewrite to people enter using the new links and some regex(search for it) to create these links.

Comment: I put an answer below because my follow-up question is so long, hope this is the right way to do this or should I have entered a new Thread?

Comment: it's not the right way to do. remove the answer. You forgot to execute the query... you just assign a string.